# Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK: Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Atul Rai\android-sdks\system-images\android-22\

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have integrate the ADT in my eclipse luna but while opening the IDE i have faces some problem.

Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:

Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Atul Rai\android-sdks\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Atul Rai\android-sdks\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Atul Rai\android-sdks\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Atul Rai\android-sdks\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Atul Rai\android-sdks\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Atul Rai\android-sdks\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Atul Rai\android-sdks\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Atul Rai\android-sdks\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.

And unable to update the my eclipse. Please help..
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case , I replaced the error file devices.xml which is error according to the error log with my devices.xml file in the dir /sdk/tools/lib/ . And save my day.

Hope it works for you .